# WKWebView strange "Unsafe attempt to load url"

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

In my Cordova + React app, I use SVG Icons, so when I render an Icon I render the React component

```
<svg className="icon">
    <use xlinkHref="assets/icons.svg#icon-plus-circle"></use>
</svg>
```

This used to work fine, but after installing cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine, which causes the app to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView, the icons are no longer visible.

In the console I get this error (formatted)

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34505CDC-DA39-4A04-8A61-1D99969F311B/Library/Application%20Support/com.mycompany.myapp/cordova-hot-code-push-plugin/2017.03.02-19.54.54/www//assets/icons.svg#icon-plus-circle
from frame with URL
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/34505CDC-DA39-4A04-8A61-1D99969F311B/Library/Application%20Support/com.mycompany.myapp/cordova-hot-code-push-plugin/2017.03.02-19.54.54/www//index.html.
Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Why do I get this error? As far as I can tell, thte domain, protocols and ports do match so I don't understand why it is complaining.

This is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.menigo.menigoapp" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>App</name>
    <description>
        App
    </description>
    <author email="test@example.com" href="http://www.example.com">
        Company
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <!--
            ldpi    : 36x36 px
            mdpi    : 48x48 px
            hdpi    : 72x72 px
            xhdpi   : 96x96 px
            xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
            xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
        -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="76" height="76" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
        <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <!-- iPad -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="50" height="50" />
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="100" height="100" />
        <!-- iPad Pro -->
        <icon src="res/icon.png" width="167" height="167" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.3.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~6.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.0" />
    <chcp>
        <auto-download enabled="false" />
        <native-interface version="5" />
    </chcp>
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
</widget>
```

This is my content-security-policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: blob: gap: * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content: blob:;">
```

Comment: What's your config.xml look like (minus secret/identifying info)?

Comment: Edited to include that

Comment: thanks -- do you have a CSP meta tag in your index.html file? If so, what is it?

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Not entirely sure why you're getting this, so this is going to be guesswork. Try adding "*" to the img-src directive in your CSP. You might also try using this plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/wkwebview-engine-localhost which would end up serving from http://locahost instead of file:// (incase the latter is the issue)